# How to write to Google Sheets using a webhook to a Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a counter using App Scripts –> Google Sheets so that every time I receive a webhook, the value is increased by 1 in a certain cell.

Everything works when I test it using a dummy function in the Google Appscript Editor, but it's not working when I send the actual webhook using the doPost(e) method.

I've spent about 2 weeks learning how to read/write Javascript, troubleshooting with YouTube videos, and reading the Google Sheets API, and I'm sooo close to cracking the code... but I'm stuck on this last part. It's probably something simple I'm missing.

Could you help please? Will pay $3 million dollars

```
//ACCEPT WEBHOOK FROM ACTIVECAMPAIGN

function doPost(e) {
  return updateMetrics(e)
}

function updateMetrics(e){
var selectedMetric = e.parameter.metric;

//GET TODAY'S DATE

var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate());
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
var monthMetrics = mm + '/' + yyyy;  

var spreadsheetId = '1UfRFM7Uz0YUqemPTVYe1lmZ5NC5v9naFvmlLvXPZuVM';  
var rangeName = monthMetrics + '!A2:I35';

var stringSheet = JSON.stringify(monthMetrics);
var stringToday = JSON.stringify(today)

var metricsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(monthMetrics)

// GET METRICS COLUMN NUMBER

function getColumnNrByName(sheet, metric) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var row in values) {
    for (var col in values[row]) {
      if (values[row][col] == metric) {
        return parseInt(col);
      }
    }
  }

  throw 'failed to get column by name';
}

var metricColumn = getColumnNrByName(metricsSheet, selectedMetric)

// GET PREVIOUS METRICS AMOUNT

function getPreviousAmount(sheet, column, metric, date, metriccolumn){

  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var data=sheet.getRange(1,column,lastRow,column+metric).getValues();


  for(i=0; i <data.length; ++i){
    if (data[i][0]==date){
      return data[i][metric];

    }
  }
}


var previousAmount = getPreviousAmount(metricsSheet, 1, metricColumn, today, metricColumn)

// SET NEW METRIC

function setNewMetric(sheet, column, metric, date, amount){

  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var data=sheet.getRange(1,column,lastRow,column+metric).getValues();


  for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
    if (data[i][0]==date){
      return sheet.getRange(i+1, column+metric).setValue(amount+1);

    }
  }
}

  var metricScript = setNewMetric(metricsSheet, 1, metricColumn, today, previousAmount);

}
```

Comment: See [the guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). You have probably not authorized the app; add a `doGet(e)` with appropriate response, republish your app or use the dev link, and see if you don't get a response. Otherwise if you're still having problems, show the code for your API request as well

Comment: thanks so much Altigraph.

I actually already deployed it as a web app and authorized it for Anonymous public access.

Here's the webhook that gets sent from Active Campaign - it contains a body with contact info, but the only thing I really need is the metric parameter at the end of the URL:

 https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyrsOYMpIQKTSx25h381GIBI5nOR-710yw7hTYOoeXJJhaC2iDx/exec?metric=TourHackingLead

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a log from the request, not just from inside the app script. Having trouble finding the answer - is it simple?

Comment: I think the problem might be because I'm not using the "return" properly?

I'm not trying to return a body to ActiveCampaign, I just want to edit the Google Sheets using the script, so I'm not sure the best way to set it up.